# Complex Gravity in Anko

Tags: kotlin, anko

I'm trying to estabilish a BOTTOM|END gravity in a FloatingActionButton via anko

```
floatingActionButton {
    id = FAB_ID∑
}.lparams {
    margin = dip(16)
    gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END
}
```

However it seems like Kotlin does not recognize the `|`operator. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin, the bitwise OR is `or` instead of `|`. `Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END` should work.

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier to read you can also use this instead of `or`:

```
floatingActionButton {
  id = FAB_ID
}.lparams {
  margin = dip(16)
  gravity = BOTTOM + END
}
```

Remember to do an import of the gravity values:

```
import android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM
import android.view.Gravity.END
```